# In Scald, is there a way to link a scald atom shown using an image style to the original image?

Tags: scald

I still haven't figured out how to link to the original atom from a display context.  For instance, if the context for an image is to downscale to a specific Image Style, I want to be able to link to the full size image (this is what users with prior exposure to WordPress expect).

So far I've tried the following:

**1.** Finding a way to autopopulate the link field when I edit atom properties (see screen shot below).

[image]

However, I've been informed that this option is not for the automatic link purpose, so I've abandoned this approach.

**2.** Setting "Link to content" to "yes" in the Manage Field display tab (see screenshot below). That does not seem to make a difference (the image does not become linked to anything).

[image]

I've tried both Scald 7.x-1.3 and 7.x-1.4 - and yes: I have cleared the cache.

Do anyone know where to find the setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

This option is not for the automatical link purpose.

What you want is always to link to the original image. This is configurable in the Manage Field display tab.

In your 2nd setup, enable "Link to content" will link to the *content* (the host entity, not the atom itself). If you want the image is linked to the atom, then there are two options:

1. Write a custom player and use it (the current player has no "link" option)
2. Configure qt the Manage display of the atom (admin/structure/scald/image/display), hide the atom itself and show the image field, with the link option.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please see my updated question. Is my second attempt what you suggest I do?

Comment: Now I even don't know what is your current setup. Is it a text field (1) or an atom reference field (2). I've update the question for the 2nd setup.

Comment: It is an atom reference field (see "Field" column in second setup screendump).  I'll investigate your revised answer and report back after I've tried your suggestions.

Comment: But in your image (1) it's the Atom properties dialog of a text field in CKEditor. Thus my question.